# Kendo date-picker for angular does not translate messages in kendo grid

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-datepicker

The issue I have is that when implemented inside a Kendo Grid cell - the date-picker remains with the default messages for "today" and "toggle" texts in English, while all other texts (months and days) seem to be translated correctly, with the IntlModule imported and LOCALE_ID provided. 
This is my html:

```
<kendo-grid-column field="endDate"
        title="{{ 'time.finalDate' | translate: { min: 'no' } }}"
        filter="date"
        editor="date"
        format="{0:dd/MM/yyyy}">
        <ng-template kendoGridCellTemplate let-dataItem let-filter let-column="column">
            {{ dataItem.endDate | dateLocalized }}
        </ng-template>
        <ng-template KendoGridEditTemplate
            let-dataItem="dataItem"
            let-column="column"
            let-formGroup="formGroup">
            <kendo-datepicker ngDefaultControl
                #datepicker
                [format]="'dd/MM/yyyy'"
                [value]="dataItem[column.field]"
                [formControl]="formGroup?.controls[column.field]">
                <kendo-datepicker-messages today="Hoy"
                    toggle="Cambiar calendario">
                </kendo-datepicker-messages>
            </kendo-datepicker>
        </ng-template>
    </kendo-grid-column>
```

And my module:

```
import { NgModule, LOCALE_ID } from '@angular/core';
import { CurrencyExchangeComponent } from './components/currency-exchange.component';
import { IntlModule } from '@progress/kendo-angular-intl';
import { DateInputsModule } from '@progress/kendo-angular-dateinputs';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [CurrencyExchangeComponent],
  imports: [
    IntlModule,
    DateInputsModule
  ],
  providers: [
    { provide: LOCALE_ID, useValue: 'es-ES' }
  ],
  exports: [CurrencyExchangeComponent]
})
export class CurrencyExchangeModule { }
```

I´ve also tried it outside the grid in a form and it seems to work, translating everything, but inside the grid the kendo-datepicker-messages doesn´t seem to work.
Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Well, it seems i have found the answer of the question "why", but I still don´t know how to fix it.

It turns out that inside the Grid Kendo is not actually displaying the date-picker I have in the KendoGridEditTemplate. This is because I have the property **editor="date"** on the **kendo-grid-column**. So it seems it´s showing an internal date editor (most probably date-picker, because it looks exactly the same). And I don´t have access to this one in order to put the kendo-datepicker-messages html with the translation of these fields.
I´ve tried removing the editor="date" from the column, but then it is not displaying any datepicker at all (it seems KendoGridEditTemplate doesn´t work with date-picker inside).

Ahother bug I´ve noticed is that in Grid the date-picker (editor="date") functions well and it saves in the formControl a **valid date**, but if in a normal **formGrroup** - when the pop-up is not used and the value is entered manually - it returns simple **string** in the formControl, which is causing issues when parsing it to a valid JavaScript date instance in order to save it to server as date (when format is **dd/mm/yyyy**, parsing it doesn´t work well with dates like 04/11/2020, because it parses it as if it was in format mm/dd/yyyy).

So, my revised html is the following (no need for the KendoGridEditTemplate):

```
<kendo-grid-column field="endDate"
    title="{{ 'time.finalDate' | translate: { min: 'no' } }}"
    filter="date"
    editor="date"
    format="{0:dd/MM/yyyy}">
    <ng-template kendoGridCellTemplate let-dataItem let-filter let-column="column">
        {{ dataItem.endDate | dateLocalized }}
    </ng-template>
</kendo-grid-column>
```